# Power BI KPI Cards Not showing the correct value

Tags: powerbi, visualization, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I am developing KPI cards in Power BI

[image]

The value here I am using is a DAX measure:

[image]

and the start of week is a column from calendar dimension table:

[image]

However, I am not able to get the correct result on this visual. Because last week's total number of event should be 18.5K

I also tried to change the trend-axis to the 'Start of Month' column, whose result is 366 which is last day's total number of events instead of last month:

[image]

and when I put the past week's total number of events in the 'target' field, it also became 8, which is so wierd. However, it should be 18.5K

[image]

The dax formula I used for `PastWeekEventCount` measure is:

[image]

Note that I have closed the automatic date hierarchy settings, so all the date columns are not hierarchy field.